# Implementation of Send is missing when calling FutureExt::boxed()

Tags: async-await, rust, future, wasm-bindgen

I'm experimenting with futures with WASM, using `wasm-bindgen-futures` and the `rust-webpack-template`; the full [working](https://github.com/SillyFreak/Rust-WASM-Async-Example/tree/75490e70e350aa31f81651ec41e8e8d60c124461) code and [problem](https://github.com/SillyFreak/Rust-WASM-Async-Example/tree/077ed8e5577fd1bc5cc1a72a7aa96308d2336a0f) code is available.

My experiment is to call an `async fn run()`, wrapped by a `fn run_js() -> js_sys::Promise`, from JavaScript. The following is working:

```
pub async fn run() -> Result<(), JsValue> {
    Ok(())
}

// Called by our JS entry point to run the example.
#[wasm_bindgen(js_name = run)]
pub fn run_js() -> js_sys::Promise {
    use crate::compat::future_to_promise;
    use futures::future::FutureExt;

    future_to_promise(async move {
        run().await?;
        Ok(JsValue::UNDEFINED)
    }.boxed())
}
```

The next step was to add a sleep function and call it from `run()`:

```
// in run:
sleep(500).await?;

pub async fn sleep(millis: i32) -> Result<(), JsValue> {
    use crate::compat::promise_to_future;

    let promise = js_sys::Promise::new(&mut move |resolve, _| {
        let window = web_sys::window().expect("should have a Window");
        window.set_timeout_with_callback_and_timeout_and_arguments_0(
            &resolve, millis
        ).expect("don't expect error on setTimeout()");
    });

    promise_to_future(promise).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

`crate::compat` converts Future 0.3 -> Future 0.1 -> Promise, and back. For completeness, here is `promise_to_future`:

```
pub fn promise_to_future(promise: Promise) -> impl Future<Output=Result<JsValue, JsValue>> {
    // promise to 0.1
    let future01 = JsFuture::from(promise);
    // 0.1 to 0.3
    Compat01As03::new(future01)
}
```

Adding this, I get a compilation error here:

```
error[E0277]: `*mut u8` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:45:7
   |
42 |     future_to_promise(async move {
43 |         run().await?;
44 |         Ok(JsValue::UNDEFINED)
45 |     }.boxed())
   |       ^^^^^ `*mut u8` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `impl core::future::future::Future`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `*mut u8`
error[E0277]: `(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:45:7
   |
42 |     future_to_promise(async move {
43 |         run().await?;
44 |         Ok(JsValue::UNDEFINED)
45 |     }.boxed())
   |       ^^^^^ `(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)`
```

(more source code context added, and abridged; full version below)

I can't make out what the error is; something here is not `Send`, but that's about as much as I understand from this.

Shouldn't this be possible in principle? Or how should I write my sleep function to work correctly?

---

Full Compiler output:

```
   Compiling rust-webpack v0.1.0 (/data/Documents/Programmieren/rust/hello-web/crate)
error[E0277]: `*mut u8` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:45:7
   |
45 |     }.boxed())
   |       ^^^^^ `*mut u8` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `impl core::future::future::Future`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `*mut u8`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::marker::PhantomData<*mut u8>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `wasm_bindgen::JsValue`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `js_sys::Object`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `js_sys::Promise`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `{i32, js_sys::Promise, fn(std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/sleep.rs:4:56: 16:2 millis:i32 {i32, js_sys::Promise, fn(std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/sleep.rs:4:56: 16:2 millis:i32 {i32, js_sys::Promise, fn(std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `{fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/lib.rs:16:43: 34:2 {fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/lib.rs:16:43: 34:2 {fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `{fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/lib.rs:42:34: 45:6 {fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/lib.rs:42:34: 45:6 {fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`

error[E0277]: `(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/lib.rs:45:7
   |
45 |     }.boxed())
   |       ^^^^^ `(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::marker::Send` for `std::ptr::Unique<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::mem::ManuallyDrop<std::boxed::Box<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)>>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `wasm_bindgen::closure::Closure<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `(wasm_bindgen::closure::Closure<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)>, wasm_bindgen::closure::Closure<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)>)`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<(wasm_bindgen::closure::Closure<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)>, wasm_bindgen::closure::Closure<(dyn std::ops::FnMut(wasm_bindgen::JsValue) + 'static)>)>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `futures::task_impl::Spawn<wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `futures_util::compat::compat01as03::Compat01As03<wasm_bindgen_futures::JsFuture>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `{i32, js_sys::Promise, fn(std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/sleep.rs:4:56: 16:2 millis:i32 {i32, js_sys::Promise, fn(std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/sleep.rs:4:56: 16:2 millis:i32 {i32, js_sys::Promise, fn(std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<wasm_bindgen::JsValue, wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `{fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/lib.rs:16:43: 34:2 {fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/lib.rs:16:43: 34:2 {fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `{fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `[static generator@src/lib.rs:42:34: 45:6 {fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::future::GenFuture<[static generator@src/lib.rs:42:34: 45:6 {fn(std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue>) -> std::result::Result<<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Ok, <std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::Error> {<std::result::Result<(), wasm_bindgen::JsValue> as std::ops::Try>::into_result}, impl core::future::future::Future, ()}]>`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `impl core::future::future::Future`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.boxed()` extension function requires the `Future` to be `Send` since [a recent change in futures](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/futures-rs/commit/3b67140adec8a76515aa3bfbabe52695b76f56d6#diff-63548cac00f39ef099b69f6caa1bdcdb). Apparently your future doesn't fulfill that constraint - likely because JS futures are only valid on the main JS thread.

If `.boxed()` happens inside the scope of your library you can use `Box::pin(future)` instead of `future.boxed()` in order to get a type erased boxed future without the `Send` requirement.